# Deploying multiple Gunicorn applications. Best process manager for easy one-click setup?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, systemd

I am a python programmer, and server administration was always a bit hard for me to immerse to. I always read tutorials and in practice just repeated the steps each time I set up a new project. I always used `uwsgi`, but realized that gunicorn is easier for simple projects like mine.

Recently, I successfully set up my first single gunicorn application with the help of this article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

But what should I do if I want to launch another app with gunicorn? Should I just make another systemd service file, like `myproject.service`? I'm looking for convenient 'one click' setup, so I can easily transfer my project to another machine, or add more gunicorn applications without much configuration. Or maybe, I should use another process manager like supervisor? What is the best solution for a newbie like me?

Sorry if my question's too dumb, but I'm really trying.

Thank you!

Comment: systemd can be a great process manager, but process management is not necessarily related to "one click setup", complicating an answer. When you say "Another app with gunicorn", it's not clear if you mean another copy of the same app with a different configuration, or a very different app. We don't know if your app needs a database (how complex it is) or how isolated your multiple apps might need to be from each other. When you say "another machine", we don't know if you mean an identical machine, one is a local Mac the other a remote Ubuntu.  Ask simpler, specific questions to attract answers

Comment: This is annoying me too. There's an `/etc/gunicorn.d` directory but i cant figure out how to make the individual gunicorn scripts actually start the app.

Comment: This is also annoying to me. I'd be interested in a solution that simplifies our workflows as web Python developers.